# Remote repository isn't up to date

Tags: git

When I try to push my changes to remote bare repository git says that it's up to date but i use a 'post-receive' hook which loads all files to another directory so I can say that it doesn't really look like it's up to date. What can i do to find out what's wrong?

My code for post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite git checkout -f
```

Comment: Where's your code for the post-receive hook?

Answer (score 2):

Try

1) Be sure that you have the correct file permission.

2) git add /path/your_files
   git commit -m "Changes"
   git push origin master  ( Check that you are in the correct repo with git branch )

Comment: 1. Do you mean permissions for directory with bare repository or my web project dir? If this is first then why there is no error from git. 2. I don't understand what is this for. I've already commited all changes.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: Desktop - Ubuntu, server - centos

Comment: Ok I got the same problem using centos and sometimes I need to make push or pull using root.

Comment: That must be it. I'll setup ssh for root tomorrow and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that my remote repository's HEAD is not my master branch. Since I made all changes in my development branch before merging it with master I had no problem with that but my last commit was made only in master branch. All I needed to do is just to change HEAD in remote bare repository by editing it's file.